# Winapi UDP IPv6 socket connection single port to multiple servers

Tags: sockets, udp, port, ipv6

My original question was poorly worded, and I didn't know what I was doing.  It is left below for reference.

The real answer to my original question was that I needed to NOT use connect() and use recvfrom() and sendto() to send/receive from multiple hosts. Which seems to work well, thanks.

I have a related question, that I hope someone might be able to answer.  Can I, with UDP, have multiple processes on the same interface and port?  I thought I remembered seeing somewhere that can be done, but has the drawback that all processes would receive all the data from the socket.  That will suffice.

I've looked a bit, and there is the SO_REUSEADDR option. In some UNIX implementations there is also SO_REUSEPORT, but that doesn't exist in Windows.  I'm trying to understand how to use the SO_REUSEADDR.  I see some questions, but, not specifically addressing my question as to if it can be done to where multiple processes can use the same interface and port for UDP.

Can someone clarify?  Thanks.

---

Original question:

I've tried to search some similar topics, such as "UDP C Sockets: Multiple Sockets Sharing Single Port"  It isn't quite the same situation.

So, here are the requirements. It is customer driven specification, and, they are not open to alternatives. So, if you say I might should be using TCP, or some other methodology, you may be right, but the customer has not shown flexibility.

Customer has literally thousands of devices in the field.  Our spec said to support 35,000 devices, though they said that actually it will probably be only around 10,000 devices for at least quite some time. We could discuss bandwidth issues, but, at the moment, that isn't my concern.  It is making the socket connections per their demands.

Basically, they want all the connections to use the same port number, that the conversations should be distinguished by IP address alone.  That's the issue.

The server we will be providing is Windows 2012 R2.  Using of course Winsock. I've seen some references to setsockopt() where you can possibly specify SO_REUSEADDR.  I've seen some UNIX references to an option SO_REUSEPORT, but, I don't see that one in the MSDN, so, maybe Windows doesn't have that one.  But, it looks like SO_REUSEADDR might can work.

The writeups I've seen on SO_REUSEADDR indicate that if you had multiple applications using the same port, they would all get all messages for that port and the individual applications would need to figure out which messages are really for which application.

Well, its not going to be multiple applications, it will be one application, connecting to multiple servers.  But, before going further, I guess I'm not quite sure why the socket layer doesn't basically distinguish sessions by IP and port combined.  Like if I had one socket talking to 192.168.1.1 on port 5000 and another socket talking to 192.168.1.2 on port 5000, even though they are the same port number, they should be distinguishable by IP address.

And, in fact, that is how server applications work, right?  Servers can accept multiple clients on, say, port 80 (multiple web clients) and the socket layer dispatches messages to the right session by IP address.  But, for my client application, doesn't seem to work that way.  Just using basic socket code, the attempt at a second connection fails with a port in use error.  And, it looks like if I get it to work with the REUSE option, both sockets would get data from both servers even though the servers have different IP addresses.  Did I understand that right, or am I totally off base?  I haven't tried coding it yet, I've just read some messages saying that is how shared ports work.

Or, is there way to "piggyback" onto a socket additional servers?  Then I could have what is to me just one socket, but, I could get data from multiple servers and then I could differentiate by IP address, assuming I can extract the source IP.

I guess I'm just saying that it seems to me that I should either be able to do this with, (in my simple two server example,) with either two sockets that each only get data from one server.  Or, with one socket that gets data from both servers.  It just doesn't seem reasonable that I would have to have two sockets that each get data from both servers.

This will of course become a bigger issue as we scale up to the 10,000 to 35,000 servers.  Am I really going to need, say 35,000 sockets, each one seeing all the data from all 35,000 servers?

But, alas, if I have to, I have to. In any case, is there sample code somewhere to do something like this in any feasable way?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why do you think you need multiple sockets? Surely you only need one, which you read as fast as possible, then you hand off the data arriving to whatever  application element is responsible for handling that source IP. You only need one for sending as well. You can scale by just providing more physical hosts.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Maybe I do only need one socket.  But, how do I open it such that it is one socket and, potentially, 35,000 servers?

Comment: It will be two way communication, so, I need to send and receive messages to those (potentially) 35,000 servers.

Comment: Are you maybe saying I can use connect() multiple times with the same socket?  If so, I did not know this. I basically thought that you could have one active connect with a socket.

Comment: You don't need to call connect() at all in UDP. As long as the peers know your IP address and port they can talk to you and you will hear them, and *vice versa.* But how *do* they know your IP address? Your new version of the question isn't correct. You can't connect() to more than one peer at a time in UDP. I've  restored the original version so we can all see what you're talking about.

Comment: Well, I confess my original question was long because I didn't understand fully what I was talking about. Perhaps when we get the answer nailed down, we can edit the question to be more useful to future seekers.

Answer (score 1):

You only need one port and one socket. Don't call `connect()` at all. Then you can send to any reachable UDP destination port, and receive from it.

Having said that, your client appears to have misdesigned the product. There is no necessity to only use one client port. All that is required is for the server to replay back to the port it received the request from, and it gets that information with every request, via the `address` parameter of `recvfrom().`

I am also wondering whether you haven't completely misunderstood the requirement. It seems much more likely that all the *devices* listen on on the same UDP port, and that the client-port constraint you mention simply does not exist.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response.  As far as how they know my IP address, I was expecting that to get handled in the connect.  I would be initiating the conversation to the devices.

Comment: You say I don't need to use connect() with UDP, but, I still can use it if I want to right?  That would be how the end devices will know my IP address.

Comment: No, it isn't how the end device will know your IP addess. All that `connect()` does is filter at your end. It doesn't send anything on the network. The end device knows your IP address via the `address` parameter of `recvfrom().` And you can't use `connect()` because you don't want the filtering. I really think you've misunderstood the client here.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I might rephrase the question to better ask the question.  But, indeed, I didn't understand sockets well.  I still don't of course, but, at least I know have better understanding.  Thanks.

Comment: I edited the question, but left the original version in tact for reference.  Basically, I need to read up on using recvfrom().  Thanks for the help.